# Retrieve all resources with same RDF/XML element name without using ID

Tags: c#, .net, rdf, sparql, dotnetrdf

Printing subjects of all my graph Triples, I saw that subjects in my data are are always URIs of the form `GraphURI/#SubjectID.` I'm able to retrieve the properties and values of one subject with a query like:

```
SELECT ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  <GraphURI/#SubjectID> ?predicate ?object
}
```

I would like to do this for all the resources that are represented by  `cim:ACLineSegment` elements in the RDF/XML serialization, though.  This is what the serialization looks like:

```xml
<cim:ACLineSegment rdf:ID="_05b8">
    <!-- some code... -->
</cim:ACLineSegment>
    <!-- other blocks -->
<cim:ACLineSegment rdf:ID="_05b9">
    <!-- some code... -->
</cim:ACLineSegment>
```

I would like something like the following.  Is this possible?

```
SELECT ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  cim:ACLineSegment ?predicate ?object
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that I would like to retrieve **all subjects containing
>   cim:ACLineSegment**, whatever the ID they may have.
>
> ```xml
> <cim:ACLineSegment rdf:ID="_05b8">
>     <!-- some code... -->
> </cim:ACLineSegment>
> ```

Your subjects don't “contain” `cim:ACLineSegment`.  Subjects don't contain *anything* in RDF.  Resources (including subjects of triples) are identified by URIs.  RDF is based on *triples* of the form {subject, predicate, object}.  The snippet you're showing is RDF/XML, which is a particular serialization of triples.  In the snippet you've shown, there are some triples of the form `{<.../_05b8>, rdf:type, cim:ACLineSegment}`.  That is, your subjects have the value `cim:ACLineSegment` as the value of the `rdf:type` property.

To explain a little bit more, suppose you had the following data. (By the way, in the future, it will be much more helpful if you provide minimal, but *complete*, sample data.  The data you provided isn't complete, and we can't run queries against it, and we can't be *sure* what it is in context.)

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ex="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#"
    xml:base="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#">
  <ex:Person rdf:ID="Mary">
    <ex:hasName>Mary</ex:hasName>
  </ex:Person>
  <ex:Person rdf:ID="Jim">
    <ex:hasName>James</ex:hasName>
    <ex:hasAge rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">34</ex:hasAge>
  </ex:Person>
  <ex:Person rdf:ID="John">
    <ex:hasName>John</ex:hasName>
  </ex:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

If you take a look at this data in the N-Triples serialization (which has just one triple per line), you'll see these triples:

```
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Mary> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Person> .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Mary> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#hasName> "Mary" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#John> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Person> .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#John> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#hasName> "John" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Jim> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Person> .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Jim> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#hasName> "James" .
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Jim> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#hasAge> "34"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
```

Notice all those `rdf:type` triples?  That's because in RDF/XML syntax ([§2.13 Typed Node Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax-typed-nodes)), an element that corresponds to a resource, has the element name as a value for `rdf:type`.   Thus, the RDF/XML above is actually shorthand for this data:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ex="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Mary">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Person"/>
    <ex:hasName>Mary</ex:hasName>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Jim">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Person"/>
    <ex:hasName>James</ex:hasName>
    <ex:hasAge rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">34</ex:hasAge>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#John">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#Person"/>
    <ex:hasName>John</ex:hasName>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

It's also helpful to view the data in N3 or Turtle syntax, because it's much closer to the SPARQL query syntax:

```
@prefix ex:    <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23432445/1281433/ex#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

ex:Mary  a          ex:Person ;
        ex:hasName  "Mary" .

ex:John  a          ex:Person ;
        ex:hasName  "John" .

ex:Jim  a           ex:Person ;
        ex:hasAge   34 ;
        ex:hasName  "James" .
```

What all of this means is that you simply want to ask for things with a specified type.  Your query would be:

```
select ?predicate ?object where {
  ?subject rdf:type cim:ACLineSegment ;     # You can use `a` instead of rdf:type.
           ?predicate ?object
}
```

Comment: As a general piece of advice (mentioned in the answer), always take a look at your data in a human readable syntax like N3/Turtle.  You'll get a better feel for what the data is, and, if you use N3 or Turtle, you practically get a template for a SPARQL query.  RDF/XML is common, but other formats are often much more useful for working with RDF.